# syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting '='

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, ruby-1.9.3

```
otherCount = @products.drop(3).inject(0) { |sum,count| sum, count }
```

My Ruby environment is 1.9.3.

`products` is an array of hashes elements. It has properties: `productName` and `count`. I want to sum up the count values of all the hashes in the `products` array (with the exception of the first 3 hashes). Documentation I've found are either too brief in their explanation or use a different Ruby environment, which may likely be the problem. The code I wrote is written as per [this document](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject).

I drop the first 3 elements, then call `inject`, with an initial value of 0, carry over variable called `sum`, and `count` is the name of the field in each of the hashes whose value I want to add up.

Comment: Maybe you should set sum equal to sum plus the game of the hash you're interested in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
inject(0) { |sum,count| sum, count }
```

to

```
inject(0) { |sum,p| sum + p['count'] }
```

---

#### Isolate the code

If you're having trouble integrating this, copy and paste these 2 lines into an `irb` session to verify this works:

```
a = [{'count' => 1},{'count' => 2},{'count' => 3}]
a.inject(0) { |sum,p| sum + p['count'] }
# => 6
```

Hopefully this helps bridge the gap.

Comment: @baph0mt What's the exact error message? (with line number info and any surrounding text) Also, did you change the `,` to a `+`?